# Полосатое изображение при заполнение bitmap черным цветом через scanline

Tags: delphi

`w` и `h` - это высота и ширина битмапа.

```
type    PRGBarray = ^TRGBarray;
        TRGBarray = array[0..30000] of TRGBQuad;
var     colorLine1 : pRGBarray;

for x:=1 to w-1 do
begin
  colorline1:=bmpin1.ScanLine[x];
   for y := 1 to h-1 do
   begin
      colorline1[y].rgbBlue:=0;
      colorline1[y].rgbGreen:=0;
      colorline1[y].rgbRed:=0;
   end;
end;
```

В результате белый битмап покрывается чередующимися вертикальными полосами: черным, красным, синим, зеленым. Как с этим бороться? Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что ScanLine просто возвращает строку в байтах. А пиксели могут кодироватся разным способом. Например 4 байта на пиксель или 2 бита на пиксель. Это определяется свойством PixelFormat (возможные значение TPixelFormat = (pfDevice, pflbit, pf4bit, pf8bit, pf15bit, pf16bit, pf24bit, pf32bit, pfCustom); ).
Но в коде есть ещё одна ошибка - ScanLine возвращает указатель на буффер, а в Вашем коде есть rgbBlue и подобные поля...
Почитайте [здесь](http://delphi.support.uz/index.php?type=tema&id=134).

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил:
bmpin1.PixelFormat:=pf32bit;